# Was "Stangen" initially used more often for football gates?

Tags: word-usage, history, austrian

In German [article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(Fu%C3%9Fball)) on football gates, there's a following quote.

> In Österreich werden Torpfosten oft als Stangen bezeichnet.

My question is - has it been always something specifically Austrian or in `Stangen` was used initially more widely but then `Torfposten` overcame alternatives. In other words, at the initial steps of the development of football, how this particular part of gates has been called?

Comment: Mir war bisher gar nicht bewusst, dass die Torstangen in Deutschland Pfosten sind. Aber das Quer-Dings, das das Tor nach oben begrenzt, heißt in Deutschland schon auch Latte, oder? Wie nennt man in Deutschland denn einen Stangenschuss (Ball prallt von einer Torstange ab)? Heißt das dort Pfostenschuss?

Comment: Du guckst keine Bundesliga…

Comment: @Janka: Ich bin Österreicher, ich *gucke* überhaupt nicht. Wenn, dann *schaue* ich. Aber nicht Balltreten. Übrigens auch nicht Schneerutschen, was für Österreich eher ungewöhnlich ist. Ich hab mal vor 25 oder 30 Jahren eine Phase gehabt, in der ich Bundesligaspiele besucht habe. Aber das war Basketball. Fußball hat mich noch nie interessiert.

Comment: Dann entgeht dir ja das dumme Sportreportergebrabbel … naja, kein echter Verlust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was definitely more often used earlier, as you may recognize from this German Brockhaus (1891 edition) [article](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/seite.html?id=126359#Foot-ball), when the differentiation between Rugby and association football was just to establish. (Funny to read, how even the number of players varied widely.)

As I understand, the cross-bar was not fully established, so what remains are just *zwei Stangen*.

Comment: Great find.
...

Comment: "jedoch auch bis zu 50" !!! )))